# Laravel redirect issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4. When "logged_in_id" is found in session I want it to continue to parse through bellow written Routes.

```
Route::get('/{anything}', function($anything)
{
    if(!Session::has('logged_in_id')) {
        return View::make('user.login');
    } else {
        //continue to check Route::get written bellow this Routing
    }
})->where('anything', '[A-Za-z0-9\/?=]+');
```

If I write `Redirect::to('/'.$anything)` then it enters the same Route and keeps on redirecting in loop. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Then the logic is wrong. Whre from do you redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a filter and then apply it to any routes that need it.

Remember to put first the routes that are more restrictive and last the more generic ones.

See the example:

```
Route::filter('logged_in', function()
{
    if(!Session::has('logged_in_id')) {
        return View::make('user.login');
    }
});

Route::get('testing',  array(
    'before' => 'logged_in',
    function()
    {
        return View::make('user.testing');
    }
));

Route::get('/{anything}', array(
    'before' => 'logged_in',

    function($anything)
    {
        return View::make('user.anything');
    }

))->where('anything', '[A-Za-z0-9\/?=]+');
```